# Jenkins Job to Update Permissions

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins configured with 'Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy' (ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy).  I would like govern Global permissions from a Jenkins job that runs a groovy script to read a JSON file from Git and then add or remove AD groups.

So far my attempts fail with errors such as these:

> 33: unable to resolve class ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy 
>    @ line 33, column 29.
>      def authorizationStrategy = new ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy()

```
import jenkins.*
import hudson.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.*
import hudson.plugins.sshslaves.*;
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*

def strategy = new ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy()

strategy.add(Jenkins.ADMINISTER, "me123")

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)
instance.save()
```

The above works fine when running from http://jenkins/script, but fails when running from a job pointing at a groovy file.

I am certain the issue is because some classes from ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy and others aren't loaded.  How can I get the above script to work in a job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While I still haven't solved for a way to reference other plugin's classes, I did discover a workaround (albeit it is limiting).  Thanks to [this source](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy) I found a way.

Using the following, I could get an instance of the existing ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy.  Casting it is unnecessary in Groovy, which helps as explicitly casting throws the runtime error as per the question.

```
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def strategy = instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()
```

And to create a new instance, I can do this:

```
def newStrategy = strategy.class.newInstance()
```

The rest of inherent to Jenkins.core.

```
newStrategy.add(Jenkins.ADMINISTER, archeusSystemAccount)
instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(newStrategy)
instance.save()
```

Final thoughts, depending upon the plugins you have installed in your Jenkins, you may want to add additional ACLs for a user/group.  As I haven't yet figured out how to import classes from plugins, I could only add strategies for Jenkins, Item, Computer, and View.